# Correct behaviour of mod operation compared to Google calculator

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What is happening here? Why is the first calculation returning an integer, but not the second calculation? What are the rules for computing mod for floats and negative numbers?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried reading the [Wikipedia article on modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)?

Answer (score 2):

I just think it extended classic rules.
$$2\times\frac{21}{2} - 16 = 5$$
So $-16 = 5 \mod \frac{21}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically $x\bmod y$ means $x-ky$ with $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $ky$ is the largest integer multiple of $y$ for which $ky\leq x$ (at least this is the definition when $y>0$; when $y<0$ conventions vary). In your example $k=-2$ both times, so $ky=-21$ respectively $ky\approx-21.069$.

By the way, most computer hardware designers either didn't understand the mathematical meaning of $\bmod$ our found it too hard to implement, so that most computer hardware implements a different remainder operation (at least when $x,y$ are integers). See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation). But the calculator software does seem to get it right here.